# Tone.js app - audio won't start until second click

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, tone.js

I'm aware that I need a user action to start Web Audio on mobile. However I have followed the recommendation to resume (in the case of Tone.js call Tone.start()) on user action but it still don't work.
Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
keyElement.addEventListener("touchstart", notePressed, false);
keyElement.addEventListener("touchend", noteReleased, false);

function notePressed(event) {
        let dataset = event.target.dataset;
        if (!dataset["pressed"]) {
            let octave = +dataset["octave"];
            oscList[octave][dataset["note"]] = playTone(dataset["frequency"]);
            dataset["pressed"] = "yes";
        }
        event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation();
    }
function noteReleased(event) {
      let dataset = event.target.dataset;

      if (dataset && dataset["pressed"]) {
        let octave = +dataset["octave"];
        oscList[octave][dataset["note"]].triggerRelease();
        delete oscList[octave][dataset["note"]];
        delete dataset["pressed"];
      }
    } 
function playTone(freq) {
        let synth = new Tone.Synth().toDestination();
        let now = Tone.now();
        Tone.start();
        synth.triggerAttack(freq, now);
        return synth;
    }
```

It works fine on the second touch, but after the first touch I get a warning about the audio context being suspended, even though the standard is that it is resumed when start() is called by a user action. I'm stumped here.

Comment: Update: If I interact with the volume slider or select box elsewhere on the page, the audio will play first touch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That Tone code looks correct. I simplified it in a CodePen and it worked on mobile on first click (iOS).

```
var keyElement = document.getElementById("play");

keyElement.addEventListener("touchstart", notePressed, false);
keyElement.addEventListener("touchend", noteReleased, false);

// Added mouse ELs to test on non-mobile.
keyElement.addEventListener("mousedown", notePressed, false); 
keyElement.addEventListener("mouseup", noteReleased, false);

var pressedTone;

function notePressed(event) {
  console.log("notePressed");
  pressedTone = playTone(440);
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
}
function noteReleased(event) {
  pressedTone.triggerRelease();
}
function playTone(freq) {
  console.log("playTone", freq);
  let synth = new Tone.Synth().toDestination();
  let now = Tone.now();
  Tone.start();
  synth.triggerAttack(freq, now);
  return synth;
}
```

Here's the link to the CodePen: https://codepen.io/joeweiss/pen/gOmeQVW

Comment: On second thought ... Is `touchstart` an event that can initiate audio on first-click?
I usually have Tone.start() behind a click until it is initialized.

Comment: Thanks. The theory is that although a user action is required, not all user actions count? I'll look into it.

Comment: Looks like you could be right. From https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#triggered-by-user-activation
An activation triggering input event is any event whose isTrusted attribute is true and whose type is one of:

change
click
contextmenu
dblclick
mouseup
pointerup
reset
submit
touchend
The event set is inconsistent across major browsers. See issue #3849.

Comment: Yeah, this is the accepted answer even tho it only came in the comments. The exact spread of accpetable user input types across browsers will be yours to discover, grasshopper. Thanks J.X. Weiss